# Who come / comes here?

Tags: pronouns, subject-verb-agreement

Dad says to his son:

> Who **come / comes** to meet you every evening. (*When Dad knows for sure that there are more than one person)*

I found from somewhere, though not very reliable, that in this case we should use **comes.**

If it is true then what is the grammar behind this?

Comment: If Dad knows that it's more than one person, he would be more likely to say "Who are the people who come to meet you?"

Comment: @KateBunting can I simply write "Who come to meet you..."

Comment: I really don't know which is 'right' because I can't imagine anyone using _who_ on its own if they know several people are involved.

Answer (score 2):

**John comes to meet me** at the station every Friday.

Question:

**Who comes** to meet you at the station every Friday?

**Who** as a question takes the **third person singular**, even if the answer involves two people. In the question, 'who' is the subject.

John and Mary come to meet me at the station every Friday.

Answer (score 1):

Well, naturally we are going to use 'comes' since that's the grammar.

However, if it's more than one person we should use the word 'people' in the sentence to indicate more than one person which doesn't necessarily contain the word 'come'.

Some examples:

> Who are the people who are going to meet you?
> Who are the people who come to visit you every evening?

Comment: That provides an alternative wording but does not really address the specific question asked by the OP.